# Calling a function an unspecified number of times

Tags: function-construction

I would like to be able to call a function an unspecified number of times. That is, I would like the generalization of something like:

```
   Sample[yi_, yf_, yinc_, zi_, zf_, zinc_]:=
          Table[{y, z}, {y, yi, yf, yinc}, {z, zi, zf, zinc}]
```

to $n$ variables, all with their own respective initial, finial and incremental values, and so I'd be calling on `Table` $n$ times. Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like :

```
sample[ranges_] := Table[Evaluate[ranges[[All, 1]]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ ranges]]
```

used like :

```
sample[{{x, 0, 3, 1}, {y, -2, 2, 1}}]
```

Comment: Or you can use `ranges__` and avoid `Sequence` and `Evaluate`.

Comment: I would use `ranges:{{_Symbol, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}` or `ranges:{_Symbol, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..` which forces the user to give the correct form for the iterators. Personally, I'd use the second form of `ranges` as it is called like `Table`: `sample[{x,0,3,1},{y,-2,2,1}]`. Also, you'd remove the `Sequence @@` shortening the code.

Comment: @Szabolcs Your solution is better, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Protecting the user by specifying the argument types is good.  Note, however, that it precludes constructs in which the endpoints of some ranges depend on the values in the current range, such as `{x, 0, 3, 1}, {y, 0, x, 1}`.

Comment: @whuber that's true. Then remove the `?NumericQ` from them which will allow the additional constructs.

Comment: Of course!  (I had done that beforehand to make sure this approach would work in that generality.)  I recommend leaving the `_Symbol` pattern for the initial argument: this solution is unlikely to work without enforcing that requirement, at least.

Comment: @whuber alternatively, you could change the middle two to `(_Symbol | _?NumericQ)`,so that both numeric and symbolic arguments are allowed. Personally, I find this construct amusing: `sample[range : With[{x = (_Symbol | _?NumericQ)}, {_Symbol, x, x, _?NumericQ}] ..]`.

Comment: @whuber btw, to ensure I get your reply, include @ followed by my user name.

Comment: Usually it's not necessary to use the "@" construct when someone has already commented: including the user name suffices.  I simply forgot to do that--sorry.

Comment: @whuber, didn't get the reply ... :P

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time, this was extremely helpful. Cheers, DB

Answer (score 2):

#### Going by the suggested syntax in your question you might find use in this:

```
sample[params__] := Range @@@ Partition[{params}, 3]
```

This does no type checking and assumes that your `params` list is in threes.
I kept it simple for ease of reading.

Example:

```
tbl = sample[3, 12, 2, 5, 1, -1]
```

> ```
> {{3, 5, 7, 9, 11}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}
> ```

On this output could use `Outer`:

```
Outer[ff, ##] & @@ tbl
```

> ```
> {{ff[3, 5], ff[3, 4], ff[3, 3], ff[3, 2], ff[3, 1]},
>  {ff[5, 5], ff[5, 4], ff[5, 3], ff[5, 2], ff[5, 1]},
>  {ff[7, 5], ff[7, 4], ff[7, 3], ff[7, 2], ff[7, 1]},
>  {ff[9, 5], ff[9, 4], ff[9, 3], ff[9, 2], ff[9, 1]},
>  {ff[11, 5], ff[11, 4], ff[11, 3], ff[11, 2], ff[11, 1]}}
> ```

#### If you allow for more flexible syntax, you might use:

```
Outer[ff, ##] & @@ Range @@@ {{3, 12, 2}, {5, 1, -1}, {3}}
```