# All values for a function with two arguments without Outer

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

Given two lists $l_a = \{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$, $l_b = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4\}$ and some function $f$ accepting two arguments, how can I produce a list of all values $f(a, b)$ for $a\in l_a$ and $b \in l_b$ using functional construction?

Comment: I would like to get {f[a1,b1],f[a1,b2],f[a1,b2],...,f[a3,b1],...,f[a3,b4]} (eg. all possible pairs)

Comment: Use `Outer[f,la, lb]` where `la` and `lb` are your lists

Comment: OK - extra question just for fun. How would you implement `Outer` using functional style?

Comment: @JarekMiszczak Something like `f[#, k] & /@ {x1,x2}/. k -> # & /@ {y1, y2, y3}`?

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for this anwser - I especially like the trick with `/. k -> # &`

Comment: Related: [Calling a function an unspecified number of times](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3343/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do `Outer[f, la, lb]` as already suggested. Alternatively you could do

```
Partition[Apply[f, Tuples[{la, lb}], {1}], Length[la]]
```

or

```
Table[f[ai,bi],{ai,la},{bi,lb}]
```

or

```
Array[f[la[[#1]], lb[[#2]]] &, {Length[la], Length[lb]}]
```

Comment: As for me the second option is great - I'm using list of matrices and I never thought about using them as iterators...

Comment: @JarekMiszczak That's a great and often overlooked syntax salt

Answer (score 7):

While `Outer` is the canonical function, in addition to the methods that Sasha shows you could use:

#### `Distribute`

```
lst1 = {1, 3, 5, 7};
lst2 = {2, 4, 6, 8};

Distribute[f[lst1, lst2], List]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], f[1, 4], f[1, 6], f[1, 8], f[3, 2], f[3, 4], f[3, 6], 
>  f[3, 8], f[5, 2], f[5, 4], f[5, 6], f[5, 8], f[7, 2], f[7, 4], 
>  f[7, 6], f[7, 8]}
> ```

#### `Through` and `Listable`

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f[a__][x_] := f[a, x]

f[lst1][lst2] // Through
```

#### `Thread` and `Map`

```
g[a__][x_List] := Thread @ g[a, #] & /@ x

g[lst1][lst2]
```

#### `ReplaceList`

In a comment [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) suggested using `ReplaceList` which is quite elegant:

```
ReplaceList[{lst1, lst2}, {{___, a_, ___}, {___, b_, ___}} :> {a, b}]
```

#### Recursion

```
h[{a_, b__}, x___] := h[{b}, x] ~Prepend~ h[x, a]
h[{a_}, x___] := {h[x, a]}

h[lst1, lst2]
```

I rather like this last one.  It works with multiple lists too:

```
h[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{{h[1, a, x], h[1, a, y]}, {h[1, b, x], h[1, b, y]}},
>  {{h[2, a, x], h[2, a, y]}, {h[2, b, x], h[2, b, y]}},
>  {{h[3, a, x], h[3, a, y]}, {h[3, b, x], h[3, b, y]}}}
> ```

Formulated using linked lists for higher performance:

```
h[{a_, b__}, x___] := {h[x, a], h[{b}, x]}
h[{a_}, x___] := h[x, a]

h[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}, {x, y}] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {h[1, a, x], h[1, a, y], h[1, b, x], h[1, b, y],
>  h[2, a, x], h[2, a, y], h[2, b, x], h[2, b, y],
>  h[3, a, x], h[3, a, y], h[3, b, x], h[3, b, y]}
> ```

Comment: If the intent doesn't imply nesting them, a nice one is also `ReplaceList[{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}}, {{___, a_, ___}, {___, b_, ___}} :> {a, b}]`

Comment: @Rojo Similar to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16457/121) which as you'll note I liked.  May I include that in my answer?

Comment: Sure. By the way, was [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16774/109) useful?

Comment: @Rojo for some reason I'm not getting `@notifications` today.  I looked at that answer briefly but I intended to return to it.  In the context of a larger `Grid` layout I believe that different sections will not align.  Sorry for not being responsive to your answer without prompting.

Answer (score 2):

#### `ListConvolve`

```
 l1 = {a1, a2, a3}; l2 = {b1, b2, b3};
 Union @@ ListConvolve[l1, l2, 1, l2, f, List]
 (* {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3], 
     f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3], 
     f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]} *)
```

#### `Tuples` - an alternative usage

```
  Tuples[f[l1, l2]]
  (* {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3], 
     f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3], 
     f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]} *)
```

To partition the flat lists above, use `Partition` or the new-in-Version-9 `ArrayReshape`:

```
 ArrayReshape[%, {Length@l1, Length@l2}] 
 (* {{f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3]}, 
     {f[a1, b4], f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2]}, 
     {f[a2, b3], f[a2, b4], f[a3, b1]}}*)
```